# Retrieve list items from sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am trying to retrieve some Items from a sharepoint 2013 online list. I know for sure that there are 3 Items in the list. Somehow the code does not return any Items. Does anybody know why not? In debugging listItems is empty.

```
User spUser = null;
SharePointContextToken contextToken;
string accessToken;
Uri sharepointUrl;

string contextTokenString = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Request);

if (contextTokenString != null)
{
    contextToken = TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(contextTokenString, Request.Url.Authority);
    sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
    accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(contextToken, sharepointUrl.Authority).AccessToken;
    var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), accessToken);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomListFacturen");

    clientContext.Load(list);

    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    query.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";

    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    if (listItems.Any())
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Items are found!!!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try and run your code, but it looks almost exactly like this code, [basic CSOM list operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks).

You don't need that first `.Load(list)` and you could try using the `CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100)` instead of the CAML.

Answer (score 0):

Your app does not have enough permissions.